# Session getting logged out when link is opened in new tab

Tags: wicket

Even after using setAutomaticMultiWindowSupport() in the application, I am unable to reatain session in 2 windows. I am using wicket 1.5

Comment: Please provide more details. Also you should upgrade to Wicket 7, 1.5 is only receiving security fixes.